# getting error while trying to deploy a React app to Azure App Service

Tags: reactjs, deployment, azure-web-app-service

I am trying to deploy a React site in Azure App Service. i get error and logs shows errors like below. Its a huge log  so i pasted a part of it.  when i run "npm run build" it works and generates a "dist" folder. but this error is when i try to publish to azure using App Azure Service extention of VSCode.

Any suggestions whats going on here.?

> modules 0 active npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE npm ERR! errno 1 npm ERR! medefis@1.0.0 build: `cross-env NODE_OPTIONS='--max-old-space-size=8192' NODE_ENV=production VIZ=true webpack --mode production --config webpack.config.prod.js --color -p --progress` npm ERR! Exit status 1 npm ERR! npm ERR! Failed at the medefis@1.0.0 build script. npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above. npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR! /home/.npm/_logs/2020-12-23T00_47_33_640Z-debug.log ../deps/libexpat/lib/xmlparse.c:6:32: warning: unknown option after ‘#pragma GCC diagnostic’ kind [-Wpragmas]\n #pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wimplicit-fallthrough"\n ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\nngrok - error unpacking binary Error: Could not find the End of Central Directory Record\n at DecompressZip.findEndOfDirectory (/tmp/8d8a6d70a2473e5/node_modules/decompress-zip/lib/decompress-zip.js:176:15)\n at _fulfilled (/tmp/8d8a6d70a2473e5/node_modules/q/q.js:854:54)\n at /tmp/8d8a6d70a2473e5/node_modules/q/q.js:883:30\n at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/tmp/8d8a6d70a2473e5/node_modules/q/q.js:816:13)\n at /tmp/8d8a6d70a2473e5/node_modules/q/q.js:624:44\n at runSingle (/tmp/8d8a6d70a2473e5/node_modules/q/q.js:137:13)\n at flush (/tmp/8d8a6d70a2473e5/node_modules/q/q.js:125:13)\n at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:79:11)\nngrok - install failed, retrying\n ⚠ Command failed: /tmp/8d8a6d70a2473e5/node_modules/cwebp-bin/vendor/cwebp -version\n/tmp/8d8a6d70a2473e5/node_modules/cwebp-bin/vendor/cwebp: error while loading shared libraries: libGL.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory\n\n\n

Comment: This post will useful to you. [How to deploy nuxt(nuxt.js) in azure(web app)? (not found module)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65019965/how-to-deploy-nuxtnuxt-js-in-azureweb-app-not-found-module/65101560#65101560)

Answer (score 0):

Do the scripts below locally:

```
npm install
npm run build
npm start
```

Deploy to Azure Web App (Check the stack Configuration):
[image]

There should be one log like this shows compressing the Modules:
[image]

It should work:
[image]